# Can Public IP's ISP location be different from owner organization location?

Tags: ip-address

I'm providing a service that is limited to Singapore only and I've region-blocked any other regions, including USA.

Today a customer from Singapore informed me that he cannot access to my server.

He was using Public IP of 168.149.0.0/16 and ARIN says it's owned by US organization, which is why it was region-blocked.

I'm confused because many whois sites tell me differenetly where this IP is from.

Q. Is it common that a public IP owned by US organization, sorted as US public IP, is actually being used in different part of the globe?

[image]

Comment: IP addresses are not geographic locations. They. Can. Be. Anywhere. If you follow the crumbs, it belongs to Broadcom. Where it is in the world is where ever broadcom puts it. It's actually being announced by Google! (private cloud)

Comment: @Ricky Sorry for the bad question but why does WHOIS locate the public IP as of USA IP? ISP is in Singapore.

Comment: There's a big difference between the location details of the *company* the IP addreses were assigned to and the location where they are used.

Comment: WHOIS reports *WHO* owns (controls/is assigned/...) the address space, not *where* it's being used. As I've said (many times), an IP address can be anywhere in the world, at any time, and can be somewhere else in seconds.

Comment: And with BGP Anycast, an IP address may be used on multiple locations at the same time.

Comment: The root problem is your region blocking *which misinterpretes inherently unreliable data*. Geolocation services have a reliability of perhaps 80-90% - the gap requires manual or semi-automatic white and black listing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As hinted in comment an IP address can actually be used anywhere in the world.
It can even be used at several places at the same time (anycasting, a technique to reach the nearest server that can handle the request).

I don't know if this is the case for other RIRs, but in Europe the RIPE do ask its members to enter the country in which the IP is supposed to be used. But there's no check on the value that is entered, so we can put whatever we want in this field, and an organization may forget to update this field if they move a network to a different location.